# Background location updates issue or kill after some time

Tags: android, service, location, tracking

I am working on tracking app. I am getting the update location and save in realm Database.

This is my code:

```js
Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    position => {
      var speed = JSON.stringify(position.coords.speed);
      var accuracy = JSON.stringify(position.coords.accuracy);
      if (speed > 0 && (accuracy < 5 || accuracy > 15)) {
        var movingLongitude = JSON.stringify(position.coords.longitude);
        var movingLatitude = JSON.stringify(position.coords.latitude);

        let arr = {
          latitude: parseFloat(movingLatitude),
          longitude: parseFloat(movingLongitude),
        };

        let newArr = AppConfig.Coordinates;
        newArr.push(arr);
        AppConfig.Coordinates = newArr;
        EventRegister.emit(Constant.SAVE_COORDINATES, 
         AppConfig.Coordinates);
      }
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error.code, error.message);
    },
    options,
  );
```

```
   public class Services extends Service {

    private static final int SERVICE_NOTIFICATION_ID = 12345;
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "TrackNTravel";

    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private Runnable runnableCode = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, Services .class);
            context.startService(myIntent);
            HeadlessJsTaskService.acquireWakeLockNow(context);
            handler.postDelayed(this, 2000);
        }
    };
    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
        // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "TrackNTravel", importance);
            channel.setDescription("CHANEL DESCRIPTION");
            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        this.handler.removeCallbacks(this.runnableCode);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        this.handler.post(this.runnableCode);
        createNotificationChannel();
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("TrackNTravel service")
                .setContentText("Running...")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .build();
        startForeground(SERVICE_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

}
```

- List[First Screen Click start button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXzzr.png) item
- [Permission granted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luz6k.jpg)
- [Permission granted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCbyk.jpg)
- [Service start show notification on top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wofXZ.png)
- [In this screen location update in background  and notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AV1EO.png)

My issue is this: why Location update stop on background mode after some time? And show notification also remove from the top after some time. This is occurring on Android 11 and 12 version only. It's working properly on 10 and below version.

Functionality is working  when app is visible (Foreground). But when app is not visible means background mode service stop. Then app open is start from splash page.

I feel that my app kill so that is happing location stop and notification also remove why this occur.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that using the firebase database.
To do that here is the step you can follow:

1. you try to initialize the firebase app every time in the background( cuz of null safety).
2. store the location data every time inside the firebase database whenever the user's latitude and longitude change. you can use the below code just pass the latitude and longitude.

```
 public static void StoreData(String id, double latitude, double longitude) {
        if (latitude != 0 || longitude != 0) {
            if (MainActivity.firebaseApp != null) { //check if firebase installed or not
                FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(MainActivity.firebaseApp);
                DatabaseReference databaseReference = database.getReference("User").child(id);
               //check if latitude and longitude changed or not
               //if changed the store that in firebase database
                if (_previousLat != latitude || _previousLong != longitude) { 
                    _previousLat = latitude;
                    _previousLong = longitude;
                    
                    databaseReference.child("latitude").setValue(latitude);
                    databaseReference.child("longitude").setValue(longitude);
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

3. Same read it from firebase database in the background using valueEventlistener