# Update location every seconds with the help of workmanager

Tags: android, gps, location, android-workmanager, foreground-service

I am working on tracking app where i get the location update in background mode from gps.
I have search on google i found  that  **Android 12 - Foreground service launch restrictions**.
So you have use Work manager insted of foreground intentService.

And **workManager minimum limit is 15 minutues for WorkManager Periodicity. Then how can i get location update every seconds in background mode**.

Because workmanager request not  run every seconds.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

When you are actively tracking the user you should use a Foreground Service. WorkManager is for cases where you care for the Work to finish, but the priority will be to save the battery.

**I can assure you that WorkManager is the wrong API for you.**

Why do you need to start the service from the background? What is your exact use case?

Check here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/background#replacing-foregound

**Some use cases for using foreground services directly are as follows:**

- Media playback
- **Activity tracking**
- **Location sharing**
- Voice or video calls

Comment: Thanks  for responding . My case is   My app  killed after some time (is occur  on  version 12 and 11 ) when app in backgroudn mode .  please check  this link  i share u the details and also screen details also  https://stackoverflow.com/q/72729156/19314251

Comment: @Adarshpavaiya  I have checked it but it is a complex question. For sure you need a foreground service, but I can't tell why it is not working. Maybe you should also check if you need to use wake locks to prevent the CPU from falling asleep. I haven't checked how they work nowadays. https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock

Comment: Thanks for response and time . Ok i check wake locks uses.

Comment: @Adarshpavaiya also you can try to remove yourself from battery optimization: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#support_for_other_use_cases

Comment: thanks . i have already try this . My problem is simple why my app  kill when my app in backgroud  even i have used start forground intent service (for latest device 11 and 12 version)

Comment: Lmao I just came here after this SO answer saying WorkManager would be preferable. ForegroundService works great unless battery saver mode is on!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67618284/android-kotlin-foreground-service-stops-after-some-time

Comment: @Adarshpavaiya did you finally solved the problem of the app being killed on Android 12 & 13 using ForegroundService? I have a similar problem, but no luck finding a solution. Thanks